# Android virtual machine manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I tried to emulate a Galaxy Nexus on eclipse using the AVMM, and yet the available android version was only limited to 4.4.4 only. What is causing the problem potentially??

Sreenshot

> [image]

My OS is Windows 7 Home Edition

Comment: Try removing space from avd name.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your device

**Example :** Change name **from** *SamsungGalaxy* **to** *samsunggalaxy*  <-correct name

(Without **spaces** and dont use **caps lock**)

Else try updating your android sdk and download again these android versions

Comment: THANK YOU! But which android versions I'm sorry???? LOOK FORWARD TO YOUR REPLY HERE, I'M DROWNING!!!><